# What is a simple example of a TensorFlow file pipeline for a language model?

Tags: tensorflow, language-model

I am building a RNN language model in TensorFlow. My raw input consists of files of text. I am able to tokenize them, so that data I am working with is sequences of integers that are indexes into a vocabulary.

Following the example in [`ptb_word_lm.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py), I have written code to build a language model that gets its training data via the [feed_dict](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#feeding) method. However, I do not want to be limited to data sets that can fit in memory, so I would like to use [file pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files) to read in data instead. I cannot find any examples of how to do this.

The file pipelines examples I've seen all have a tensor of some length *n* associated with a label that is a tensor of length 1. (The classic example being a 28 x 28 = 784 item tensor representing an MNIST bitmap associated with a single integer label that ranges from 0 to 9.) However, RNN training data consists of a vector of *n* consecutive tokens and a label also consisting of *n* consecutive tokens (shifted one ahead of the vector), for example:

```
"the quick brown fox jumped"
vectors (n=3): the quick brown, quick brown fox, brown fox jumped
labels (n=3): quick brown fox, brown fox jumped, fox jumped EOF
```

Can someone give me a code snippet that shows how to write a file pipeline to feed this shape of data into a TensorFlow graph?